# Adding a custom text label in Lightswitch 2013

Tags: javascript, lightswitch-2013

This seems like a relatively simple issue however I don't seem to be able to find anything on the internet or I'm not searching for the right thing so here's my question:

I have added a custom string parameter to my screen... lets call it Title. Now what I want to do is add this to the screen and underneath the label that says title, I want it to say Book. So im not passing anything into it, I just want to add a custom label to my screen, I've tried this with little success

```
contentItem.screen.Title == "Books";
```

Any help would be great, cheers :)

Comment: Solved it:
    element.innerText = "Book";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

```
myapp.ViewBookshelf.Books_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {

element.innerText = "Books"
element.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
element.style.fontSize = "21px";
};
```

for Ints or Booleans

```
contentItem.value = false;
contentItem.value = 0;
```